# Rails render not opening new page with searchkick

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to make a search kick results page. However when i click search the console states i've got the correct id but the results page isnt opening.

I have this for my controller

```
  def search
    @events = Newevent.search params[:search]
    render 'events/results'
  end
```

I also have this as my search form

```
  <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
    <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], class: "form-control", autocomplete: "off" %>
    <div class="input-group-btn">
      <%= submit_tag "Search", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

And this is inside the results html.erb

```
<% @events.each do |event| %>
<h1>Test</h1>
<%= event.eventname %>
<% end %>
```

Heres what the console states when i start the search

```
Started GET "/search_events?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=capital&commit=Search" for ::1 at 2015-11-21 15:18:33 +0000
Processing by NeweventsController#search as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "search"=>"capital", "commit"=>"Search"}
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
  Newevent Search (9.8ms)  curl http://localhost:9200/newevents_development/_search?pretty -d '{"query":{"dis_max":{"queries":[{"match":{"_all":{"query":"capital","operator":"and","boost":10,"analyzer":"searchkick_search"}}},{"match":{"_all":{"query":"capital","operator":"and","boost":10,"analyzer":"searchkick_search2"}}},{"match":{"_all":{"query":"capital","operator":"and","boost":1,"analyzer":"searchkick_search","fuzziness":1,"prefix_length":0,"max_expansions":3,"fuzzy_transpositions":true}}},{"match":{"_all":{"query":"capital","operator":"and","boost":1,"analyzer":"searchkick_search2","fuzziness":1,"prefix_length":0,"max_expansions":3,"fuzzy_transpositions":true}}}]}},"size":100000,"from":0,"fields":[]}'
  Newevent Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "newevents".* FROM "newevents" WHERE "newevents"."id" = 20
  Rendered events/results.html.erb within layouts/application (1.6ms)
  Rendered layouts/_navigation.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered layouts/_messages.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 93ms (Views: 79.5ms | Searchkick: 9.8ms | ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)
```

Comment: what do you mean by: "results page isnt opening"?

Comment: Ha, Hi again, Its i was expecting the page to redirect to results.html.erb however its just staying on the initial page where the search engine is

Comment: in your search form, do you use `remote: true`?

Comment: Indeed i do I'm guessing thats the issue? *edit* That was the issue! Working perfectly now! Please add it as an answer so i can award it :)

Comment: Oh, I just wrote an answer before read your comment ;) with much more explanation why I can know that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base on your server's log, I think you setup your search form as a remote form (you will see you have `remote: true` in your `form_for` tag)

```
Processing by NeweventsController#search as JS
```

Do you see text: **as JS** in the above line. That's because you submit a remote form. That means when you submit your form, the form will call ajax to server wait for server to return a js code to run on client side.

To solve your problem, just remove `remote: true` in your `form_for` tag, and everything will be ok ;)